# Django UnitTest with Mock

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing an Unit-Test for a Django class-based view.

```
class ExampleView(ListView):

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(EampleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         ## do something else

     def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
         return self.get_data()

     def get_data(self):
         call_external_API()
         ## do something else
```

The key issue is that `call_external_API()` in `get_data()`.

When I am writing Unit-test, I don't really want to call external API to get data. First, that will cost my money; second, I can easily test that API in another test file.

I also can easily test this `get_data()` method by having an unit-test only for it and mock the output of `call_external_API()`.

However, when I test this whole class-based view, I simply will do

```
self.client.get('/example/url/')
```

and check the status code and context data to verify it.

In this case, how do I mock this `call_external_API()` when I am testing the whole class-based view?

Comment: Not sure what the difference is in your two scenarios. Why can't you just mock it in the same way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What your are looking for is [`patch` from `unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch). You can patch `call_external_api()` by a `MagicMock()` object.

Maybe you want to patch `call_external_api()` for all your tests in class. `patch` give to you essentialy two way to do it

- decorate the test class
- use `start()` and `stop()` in `setUp()` and `tearDown()` respectively

Decorate a class by `patch` decorator is like decorate all test methods (see documentation for details) and the implementation will be very neat. Follow example assume that your view is in `my_view` module.

```
@patch("my_view.call_external_api", autospec=True)
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_get_data(self, mock_call_external_api):
        self.client.get('/example/url/')
        self.assertTrue(mock_call_external_api.called)
```

More sophisticate examples can be build and you can check how you call `mock_call_external_api` and set return value or side effects for your API.

I don't give any example about start and stop way to do it (I don't really like it) but I would like to spend some time on two *details*:

1. I assumed that in your `my_view` module you define `call_external_api` or you import it by `from my_API_module import call_external_api` otherwise you should pay some attention on [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)
2. I used `autospec=True`: IMHO it should be used in every patch call and [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing) explain why very well

Answer (score 3):

You can mock the `call_external_api()` method when testing the classed based view with something like this:

```
import modulea
import unittest
from mock import Mock

class ExampleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

     def setUp(self):
         self.call_external_api = modulea.call_external_api

     def tearDown(self):
         modulea.call_external_api = self.call_external_api

     def get_data(self):
         modulea.call_external_api = Mock(return_value="foobar")
         modulea.call_external_api()
         ## do something else
```